# Token to authorize an external app NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have a setup of Mongo, Express, ReactJS, NodeJS. My app requires users to log in and then they can do certain actions. Each user get a temporary JWT token.

I want to allow an external WordPress website to send me an array using a POST request.
I've figured out how to do this (using CURL) but my app rejects any requests without a JWT token.

Thing is, I don't want users from WordPress to log in so they have a token. I need a token for the wordpress site. I need some "secret key" so that the WordPress site will be authorized to speak to my app.

So, In my app I created new routes like so:

```
app.use('/api/external', externalRoutes)
const { getExternalOrder } = require('../controllers/external')
router.post('/', getExternalOrder)
```

but right now, anyone get send POST to /api/external. So I want to add a "secret key" to make sure it's a verified request.

Answer (score 0):

If the communication between the WordPress site and your application is server-to-server communication; can you use client credential flow where the WordPress site obtains an access token from your IDP using client credentials i.e. client id and client secret...

Other options:

- HMAC & shared secret - I've actually done this approach with
  WordPress talking to protected external routes.
- basic auth
- client certificates